# How do I change a image on a Button using Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, image

How do I toggle between two images on a `Button`? 
I have a "Lock" and "Unlock" image I would like to use on the same button.

So far I have used the property window to set a single image..

UPDATE: 
Many good answers, but I should have mention that my two images is in the Property folder. How do I access them with a relative path?

Comment: Use CheckBox.Appearence=Button and ImageList to set ImageIndex when checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will most likely have to change the `Button.Image` property in the code-behind. See the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.image.aspx) for information and a sample on how to do this.

Comment: I had to set `Button.Image` and I used `Properties.Resources.lock_open` 
to get to my file. It works perfectly. I only wrote about the toggle function to say that it was a new situation were two images were needed. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 8):

You can change a image of Windows Form Button using 2 Methods

**Method 1 for Relative Path**

```
button1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\jk\Desktop\icons\image.png");

button1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\jk\\Desktop\\icons\\image.png");
```

**Method 2 For Resources Image**

```
this.button1.Image = NameSpace1.Properties.Resources.Image2.png;
```

you can also visit [MSDN Library: ButtonBase.Image Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.image.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Easy:

```
button1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\forestfloor.jpg");
```

P.S. Before set image, check if it exist

Answer (score 0):

You would have to code.

```
if(locked)
  Button.Image = Images.Lock;
else 
  Button.Image = Images.Unlock;
```

where `Images` is, say, a Resource you have created through the designer.