# C# WinForms - Picture in Button

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

How can i insert a picture in button? For example:

Picture + Text in button

[image]

Here you can see download icon and text. I wanna do the same thing, put image in button

Comment: It's not very hard to find an Image property from the button's properties window.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a duplicate of;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895745/how-do-i-change-a-image-on-a-button-using-windows-forms

Answer (score 0):

Done it

```
var image = Downloader.Properties.Resources.download_icon;
            var resized = new Bitmap(image, new Size(15, 15));

            DownloadLeft.Image = resized;
            DownloadLeft.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```